# 14.04 installation crashed - now machine is dead

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, crash

I was half way through an upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 when my machine crashed. At this point it had been running for over an hour doing the upgrade so I have no idea what caused it. I was merrily reading a book when the machine just rebooted. I am pretty convinced it was only about one third done with the upgrade.

Unfortunately it did not even get to the login screen after the reboot. Background goes black-grey and it just hangs - no hotkeys work - nothing.

I have just booted from CD with a very old version (10.10) and managed to get to the internet to ask this question.

Is there any way I can 're-do' or 'continue' the upgrade from the CD boot, or do I have to wipe my primary partition and start from scratch ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can continue. Lack of power will disrupt the installation and clear it, so you might have to wipe the primary partition and install Ubuntu again.